# How to install Java and Groovy in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, java, groovy

I'm a new user to Ubuntu! so I need your help.  How do I install Java and Groovy in Ubuntu??
Please give step by step instructions.

Comment: Please see http://askubuntu.com/questions/5567/how-to-install-the-sun-java-jdk

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This really couldn't be simpler in Ubuntu.  First open a terminal window:

<kbd>Applications</kbd>-><kbd>Accessories</kbd>-><kbd>Terminal</kbd>

then in the window that comes up type:

```
user@computer:~$ sudo apt-get install groovy
```

Enter your password when it asks for it, and enter `Y` when it asks you if you want to continue.

Groovy will download, along with all its requirements (including Java) and install automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Although automatic install is really nice feature, the repository version of Groovy may be not the current one.

If you want to be sure about the version you will install a bit more complicated method is necessary.

- Download latest zip binary release from [Groovy site](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Download) and unzip it where do you like
- Add groovy location to the path. To do this edit the `~/.profile` file and add following lines at the end:

  ```
  export GROOVY_HOME="/path/to/the/place/you/extracted/the/zip"
  PATH="$GROOVY_HOME/bin:$PATH"
  ```
- Logout and login or in terminal launch the command:

  ```
  source .profile
  ```